# Aws cognito email verification error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am new to aws and need some help with a cognito issue. I am trying to use aws cognito for registering user.

User passes email and password to cognito and then will receive an email with verification link. However, when clicking on the link for verifying email, always get the following error message:

"User cannot confirm because user status is not UNCONFIRMED."

But, in the cognito user pool, the user status before email verification was indeed "UNCONFIRMED".  I am wondering why aws sends this message.

In addition, the user status did become "Confirmed" after clicking the link (even though with that confusing message).

Any idea? thanks!